# Resizing different sized images using CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a webpage which will show different images at different times. Some images are wider than the webpage, some are taller, some are both. Is there a way using CSS to limit to the larger of the two (for example if the image was too wide for the screen, the image would reduce both height and width to keep the aspect ratio the same until the width fit in. The same scenario if the height is too tall).

Ive managed to reduce an image which was originally ~1500px x 2000px so its width fits on, but the scroll bar is still needed to see the bottom part of the image. Ive achieved this by have a container div with the following:

```
#container {
    min-width: 740px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and then setting the div containing the image to width:100% and height:100%. The width changes to fit, but the height doesnt!

---

edit: using the two examples given in the answers below i get:

[image]

which is just constraining the image to a certain size which I could do just by setting the width and height properties of the image. I want it to maximize to the screen while maintaining aspect ratio, so if its a wide image the entire width will be shown (albeit with blank space above and below to maintain aspect ratio) and likewise if it is a tall image, the entire height of the image is shown with blank space around the sides. Sorry if my original question didnt get this point across succinctly!

Comment: Are you using `background-image` or `<img>`s? If the former try `.image{
    background-image: url("your/url/here");
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}`

Comment: Very hard to understand from your question what kind of result you expect. If you have a fixed container and you want different images to fill the container from edge to edge just use `#container img { width:100% }` and the image will scale accordingly to the parent container size.

Comment: @Giovanni please explain how big you want your image to appear? Do you want to fill entire browser window while maintaining aspect ratio of image? Both examples below create a wrapper element in example size, which can be set however you want. If you will change width and height of the image then you loose aspect ratio! So again: please explain clearly how you want your image to be displayed! Preferably paste some code or link of your website so we can see in what context you are putting your images.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved with `img` tags without adding Javascript. Instead of:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg">
```

Use

```
<div class="preview" style="background-image:url(myimage.jpg)"></div>
```

And then add some CSS:

```
.preview {
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: wont this set the image to 300px x 300px?

Comment: Yes, I just took some example size since you didn't say what size you would like to constrain to. Actually because of the `contain` it doesn't resize to that size, it just constrains it to that size.

Comment: well i want it constrained to either full width or full height, whichever is greater (ie I want the whole image showing: if the image is wider than it is high reduce to 100% width, if the image is higher than it is wide reduce to 100% height)

Comment: That is what it does now. The sizes are there because your requirement cannot be fulfilled without constraining both max width and height - those are 300px in this sample now.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="background-image: url('pic1.jpg');"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
   width: 600px;
   height: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

But in any case if you want to fill fixed container with variable image size you will have to sacrifice some of the image to overflow the content boundaries if you want to maintain image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Maintains aspect ratio, but forces it into a different container aspect ratio. This seems like the suitable solution that I personally use for slideshows and whatnot.